# DXA 1.4 Managing empty regions

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

How we can manage empty regions, ones without a physical jsp, with the new TLD model?

We want to reproduce this behaviour without creating the region:

`<tri:entities region="regionName" />`

With the current DXA, I have always created the region, and then inside call to the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to delegate rendering of a Region to a Region View.

If, for whatever reason, you want to render all Entities in a Region without using a Region View, you can use a foreach loop to iterate over all Entities and then use the `dxa:entity` tag to delegate rendering of the Entity to the appropriate Entity View.